# How to limit CPU/Memory - GitHub actions self hosted runners

Tags: github, github-actions, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

I'm running multiple self hosted runners in one machine.

I'd like to give specific # of CPU cores/memory to each runners.

How can I achieve this?

ps) I can not use VM.
ps) As I googled, launching via docker have some limitations as I googled. Docker commands inside docker?